# Adding numbers to a list when prompted

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I am trying to append numbers into a list already created when prompted for the number.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
for numbers in y:
    if y > 5:
        x.append(y)
        print x
    else:
        print "List remains the same"
```

But, even if I type in 3, it still appends it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it in Python 2:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = int(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
if (y) > 5:
    x.append(y)
    print x
else: print "List remains the same"
```

Comment: Please do not advocate the usage of `input` - it's dangerous.

Comment: @orlp the OP must be using Python 2 because he originally used `raw_input` this is why I put `input`

Comment: I know, that was not my point. You should __never__ use `input`. It uses `eval`, and is a lazy and dangerous solution.